# How is it possible to find the current row index when a google form is submitted/re-submitted? Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Is it possible to find out the current row index when a google form is submitted (or re-submitted using the Edit Response URL)?

I have been finding the last row number and then based on that an email is sent to the person who submitted the google form. This causes a problem when the same person edits his response at a later date and submits again, this leads to only the last row details being sent to the submitter - not his row.

I am aware of using the below functions:

```
e.values or e.range
```

I am just wondering if using them in google apps script, if its possible to find the current row?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `e.range.getRow()`?

Comment: @SandyGood I didn't try that, thank you - that did work. Is there any other way to find the current row of submission? Or is this the only way?

Comment: That's probably the easiest way.  You could get values from the Form submission, then get all the data in the spreadsheet, loop through all the data, and compare it to the data in the current submission, and make a match.  Or if you had a column with some unique value, you could search that column for a unique value.  But if `e.range.getRow()` is reliable, there's really no point in processing all that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
e.range.getRow()
```